# GetDeleteCommand DataAdapter with a temporary table in Sybase

Tags: sap-ase, dataadapter, temporary

Porting MSSQL Application to Sybase (ASE 15.0), and experiencing a problem when I call `GetDeleteCommand`.
The error reported is:

> Dynamic SQL generation for the DeleteCommand is not supported against
>   a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

The problem only occurs for temporary table, identical non-temporary table works fine.
Table contains a primary key.

Reproduced using test program below.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    using System.Data;

    namespace DataAdapterTempTable
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                String ConnectionString = "Provider=ASEOLEDB;Data Source=devsun3:5003;Initial Catalog=ctc;User ID=aigtac12;Password=aigtac12;"; // sybase connection string
                //String ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=fiji;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=nxgn0811;Integrated Security=SSPI"; // mssql connection string

                String TableName = "#alex_temporary_table_test"; // does not work for sybase
                //String TableName = "alex_real_table_test"; // works for sybase + mssql

                String CreateStatement = "create table " + TableName + " (currency_id varchar(4) primary key, rate  decimal(25,6), format   char(1))";

                String SelectStatement = "select * from " + TableName;

                try
                {
                    OleDbConnection con = null;
                    con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
                    con.Open();

                    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = CreateStatement;
                    int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    OleDbCommand cm1 = con.CreateCommand();
                    cm1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cm1.CommandText = SelectStatement;
                    OleDbDataAdapter DA2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cm1);
                    DataTable DT2 = new DataTable();
                    DA2.FillSchema(DT2, SchemaType.Mapped);
                    OleDbCommandBuilder cmdbldr = new OleDbCommandBuilder(DA2);
                    DA2.InsertCommand = cmdbldr.GetInsertCommand();

                    DA2.DeleteCommand = cmdbldr.GetDeleteCommand(); // this line fails in sybase for temporary table

                    DA2.UpdateCommand = cmdbldr.GetUpdateCommand();
                    DA2.Fill(DT2);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted Sybase support, turns out I had to update some system stored procedures. There is a folder that ends with "oledb\sp", and I had to run a .bat file from the folder. I got the latest ebf and ran the batch file install_oledb_sprocs.bat, the problem went away. Worth mentioning, that sybase 15.5 did not have the issue without patching.

P.S. Thank you to 'aF' for your time looking into the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the select statement, instead of `*` use the column names.

Comment: But it does have a primary key

Comment: Please try with a different #temporary table name. Just #alex for example.

Comment: try to use the column names instead of just * (in the selectstatement)

Comment: Tried with listing columns as well. I contacted Sybase support, turns out I had to update some system stored procedures. There is a folder that ends with "oledb\sp", and I had to run a .bat file from the folder.  I got the latest ebf and ran the batch file install_oledb_sprocs.bat, the problem went away. Worth mentioning, that sybase 15.5 did not have the issue without patching.